# Null Pointer Exception, How can i print an array with these codes

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have a code. This code splits multi-paragraph text with spaces or quotes. I want put the splitting parts into an array. But when I use that way, I get `NullPointException` error. What do you think about that?

```
    arrays = null;

            //arrays [k] = str.substring(j , (i)).trim() ;




    //System.out.println(arrays [k]);
```

**The arrays and scan are defined above the main.
When i try the ArrayList, i get output but it is multiple. 
For example: 
a b c d
a b c d
   .
   .
Multi-lines of same thing.

Comment: the variable `arrays` isn't initialized anywhere, after its declaration. Unless it is required that you use arrays, you might use an `ArrayList`, and when you exit the reading loop you can convert it to an array.

Comment: ArrayList is giving me wrong output

Comment: The wrong output has to do with your control flow (the reading loop and the conditionals driving the text processing) and not with you using lists over arrays.

Comment: Okay, so what will I do about that?

Comment: You'll have to rethink your algorithm, or debug it to pinpoint what goes wrong and where in the code. I'd use a pre-typed text read in one shot from file, then I would apply the splitting algorithm to it and debug step by step until I figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You declared your `arrays = null;`, so when you try to access `arrays`, you are accessing `null` in fact, so you get a NullPointerException. You want to declare your `arrays` as `String[] arrays = new String[x]` with `x` being the size of the array. If you don't know the size in advance, you would want to use an `ArrayList`. You declare that by saying `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()` (from Java 5 up for the generics). You add elements by saying `list.add(item);`

Answer (score 0):

what i can see by just a quick look is you have declared  `String[] arrays = null;` but not initializing it and then using it `arrays [k]`, this is a null pointer. you have to initialize it. Something like `String[] arrays = new String[6];`. You might want to add the length dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, but if the file's size is bigger than my entered size?

Comment: did not got your question. Please explain what do you mean by "than my entered size" ?

Comment: OP means "if the size is not known in advance, I cannot initialize an array of unknown size"

Comment: For example = new String [26].. If my splitting parts are major than, bigger than 26. (Just example.)

Comment: Ok. No worries, you can create a starting size array lets say 10 and then you can write logic to grow it each time you need more. Or just use Collection List

Answer (score 0):

just try using "[try catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)"

compare using "compareTo" method

```
char c1 = 'x'; 
char c2 = 'y'; 
c1.compareTo(c2)
```

and dont initialize array as null

Comment: compare using "compareTo" method
char c1 = 'x';
char c2 = 'y'; c1.compareTo(c2) and dont initialize array as null

Comment: If I don't initialize as null, the compiler gives me error

Comment: String[] arrays = new String[1024]

Comment: If the splitting parts bigger than 1024, i don't know how many lines in text.